# Show correct chevron on data-toggle - css only

Tags: html, css

I am making use of the following css to toggle a chervon, but the problem is at start-up the wrong chevron is display. As soon as you start the toggle, it works. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

CSS:

```
.arrow-toggle .fa-chevron-down,
.arrow-toggle.collapsed .fa-chevron-right {
    display: inline-block;
}

.arrow-toggle.collapsed .fa-chevron-down,
.arrow-toggle .fa-chevron-right {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="foo in vm.bar track by $index"
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#task{{$index}}"
    class="arrow-toggle">
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

See the Pen [Chevron Toggle Issue](http://codepen.io/Programm3r/pen/JbWgEj/) by Richard  ([@Programm3r](http://codepen.io/Programm3r)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add class `collapsed` to the `tr` initially

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="foo in vm.bar track by $index"
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#task{{$index}}"
    class="arrow-toggle collapsed">
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

The `.fa-chevron-down` is hidden if the `tr` has the class `.collapsed`

```
.arrow-toggle.collapsed .fa-chevron-down,
.arrow-toggle .fa-chevron-right {
    display: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbWwdN

Comment: I was going to, but I had to wait 8 minutes before I could mark is as the answer.